# How can I display fractional seconds in DT tables

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I would like to see the milliseconds in `DT` datatables:

```
options(digits.secs=6)
library(data.table)
d = data.table(x = 1:10,time = as.POSIXct('2015-03-23 12:00:00.123'))
library(DT)
datatable(d)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
options(digits.secs=6)
library(data.table)
d = data.table(x = 1:10,time = as.POSIXct('2015-03-23 12:00:00.123'))
d$time = strftime(d$time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3')

View(d)
library(DT)
datatable(d)
```

Gives:

```
Show  entries
Search:
x   time
1   1   2015-03-23 12:00:00.122
2   2   2015-03-23 12:00:00.122
3   3   2015-03-23 12:00:00.122
4   4   2015-03-23 12:00:00.122
```

Comment: So you're casting to string? Is it the only way?

Comment: Not sure if it's the only way. I tried `OS` directly in `POSIXct` but it looks like it's not supported